# Setup Autocompleteplace setupAutocompleteTextView

Tags: java, android

I am facing an issue with Google Maps Place API, on setupAutocompleteTextView

mAdapter = new PlaceAutocompleteAdapter(this, googleApiClient, BOUNDS, null);

```
    pickUpText.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    pickUpText.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            InputMethodManager inputManager =
                    (InputMethodManager) GoCabActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(pickUpText.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
            AutocompletePrediction item = mAdapter.getItem(position);

            getLocationFromPlaceId(item.getPlaceId(), new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(@NonNull PlaceBuffer places) {
                    final Place place = places.get(0);
                    LatLng latLng = place.getLatLng();
                    if (latLng != null) {
                        gMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
                        onPickUpClick();
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    });
    destinationText.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    destinationText.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            InputMethodManager inputManager =
                    (InputMethodManager) GoCabActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(destinationText.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
            AutocompletePrediction item = mAdapter.getItem(position);

            getLocationFromPlaceId(item.getPlaceId(), new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(@NonNull PlaceBuffer places) {
                    final Place place = places.get(0);
                    LatLng latLng = place.getLatLng();
                    if (latLng != null) {
                        gMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
                        onDestinationClick();

                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

no error on logcat but the function still not working

Comment: You should [edit] your question with information about HOW it's "not working".

Comment: solved by new PLACE API

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a similar project to yours, the issue with the autocomplete function start from the [Googlemap](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/map)
it has been updated to a new version  and the [places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/intro) required to work with the Map is out of date and has been redesign differently.

What you need to do is update the dependencies.
secondly,add new [places autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/autocomplete#option_1_embed_an_autocompletesupportfragment) function